# Use namespace in global context with autoloader

Tags: php

Due to an external library I have to use namespaces. Since I havn't used namespaces before I realised using a namespace won't work with my `__autoload()`. The code below will say

> Failed to load class Foo\Bar\NamespaceClass, please update the autoloader!

How may I fix this? The `Foo` class is just a wrapper around the external library.

```
// This is my autoloaded class file
use Foo\Bar\NamespaceClass;

class Foo
{
    public function Bar()
    {
        $namespaceClass = new NamespaceClass();
    }
}

// This is a separate file calling my class "Foo" from global namespace
$myAutoloadedClass = new Foo();
$myAutoloadedClass->Bar();
```

Comment: @artragis No, I do not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand how namespaces work. I recommend you to read articles about that, for instance [this one on nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/namespacing-in-php-2/).

Furthermore, I recommend you to use [the PSR-0 standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md). Almost all 3rd-party libraries follow that and they come in with a autoloader which you can use directly.

At last, you said you use an external library. Have you take a look at [composer](http://getcomposer.org)? That a really great tool to help you autoloading, updating and using external libraries. I recommend you to watch the great screencast of KnpUniversity: ["The Wonderfull World of Composer"](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/composer)

Answer (score 0):

You should update the autoloader.